# Translation Invariance of Time Change of Brownian motion

Tags: probability-distributions

I'm kind of not 100% sure about this: Let $B$ be a Brownian Motion defined on some Probabitlity space  $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}_t,\mathbb{P)}$ and $\phi^{-1}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ increasing continuous function.  Is it true that for any $\varepsilon>0$ $ (\varepsilon\in \mathbb{R})$ and all $t\in \mathbb{R}$: $$\varepsilon B(\varepsilon^{-2}\phi^{-1}(t))\stackrel{d}{=}B(\phi^{-1}(t))$$

Should be true but i might be wrong.

Comment: Who is $\varepsilon$?

Comment: Yes it's true just by Brownian scaling. Set $\varphi^{-1}(t)=s$ to make it more obvious.

Comment: Alright thank you very much! $\varepsilon>0,$ $\varepsilon\in \mathbb{R}$